# C# Razor Page - Include @section Scripts inside _Layout (Dot net core)

Tags: razor, .net-core, razor-pages

Assume the following `@section` code for a dynamic script received from `Controller/Model`: *(dotnet core v3)*

```
        string scriptHtml = ViewData["scriptData"];
        @section Scripts {
            @if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptHtml)){
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    @Html.Raw(scriptHtml)
                </script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='~/js/appcore/site.reuse.js'></script>
            }
        }
```

I want to use this **inside _Layout.cshtml**, in other words: I want to be able to include a Scripts section inside `_Layout.cshtml`, that will be consistent across all pages that include it.

So basically, `_Layout.cshtml` should look like this (Only the Javascript section showed):

```
@section Scripts {
    @if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptHtml)){
         <script type='text/javascript'>
              @Html.Raw(scriptHtml)
          </script>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='~/js/appcore/site.reuse.js'></script>
     }
}
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)  <!-- not rendered because it is not in the parent 'ie. Index.cshtml' page....
```

When this `@section` is *not inside _Layout.cshtml* but moved to the parent razor page (for instance Index.cshtml) calling `_Layout.cshtml` it will be included correctly.  This however means I will have to `@section` this script for every razor page.

What can I do to include a 'dynamic' Javascript script and make it reusable across all pages that use `_Layout.cshtml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Section` blocks are not intended to be used in a *layout page*, unless it is a child layout to another layout page.  Sections are only used (collected) in the *View page*.
Any `@Script` sections in `_Layout` will be ignored.

Because this is to be shared (reused) by several pages, just include it like a normal embedded script.  The condition will make sure it is included.

So just include the **conditional block** in the `_Layout.cshtml` (or layout file), **remove the `@Section` tag** and move it closer towards the other scripts.

Updated `_Layout` page:

```
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted"></footer>

    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptHtml)){
         // This condition will ensure to correctly include when not empty
         <script type='text/javascript'>
              @Html.Raw(scriptHtml)
          </script>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='~/js/appcore/site.reuse.js'></script>
     }

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Note: This `@RenderSection` will only include scripts that are in the *View*.

Comment: So, you mean to say that I should just add it into each `parent page` as already doing (Index, About, etc)?  That is unfortunate :(  Also, is there a way to make a 'child layout' for '_Layout' so that I can include it in some other way?

Comment: No - if it appears in all the pages that use the layout, put it in the layout. Updated my answer to clarify that

Comment: Ok I think I know what you are trying to say.  I can't _use_ sections as I wanted, but because its something that is _reusable_ I can simply embed it as a (normal) _non-@Section_ script.  Thanks - was hoping I could 'bundle an @Section' script section inside _Layout.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I have now slightly altered my idea, but generally it works now.